# Assignment Rule : If case.subject already exists - move to different queue. Possible?

Tags: case

Can anyone help me out with this requirement .I shall appreciate your help.

Do we have an option to write an assignment rule :

say if the subject is already exist in the existing cases move to a different queue???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

For existing records you have to write the logic in trigger . But if your requirement is like whenever the case is created then you can go with option of writing assignment rules. And to fire assignment rules from Apex class you can have this piece of code after inserting the case

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;
objCase.setOptions(dmo);
```

*objCase is new instance of Case object in Apex class

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to write a trigger to perform logic this complex. Assignment rules can't query existing records in the database.